# How do you render views in an each loop without container objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller that has a property which is an array of subcontrollers.  Each subcontroller has a view property that I want to render.  This piece of code throws an error:

```
{{#each subcontrollers}}
    {{view this.view}}
{{/each}}
```

If I wrap the subcontrollers into objects that look like `Ember.Object.create({key: subcontroller})`, then this code works fine:

```
{{#each subcontrollerContainers}}
    {{view this.key.view}}
{{/each}}
```

Another way achieve this is with a `CollectionView`:

```
{{#collection subcontrollerCollection}}
    {{view view.content.view}}
{{/collection}}
```

This seems counterintuitive to me.  What is the real difference between `{{view this.view}}` and `{{view this.key.view}}`?  What exactly is the `CollectionView` doing differently?

Here's my JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tuxob/7/edit

jQuery 1.10.2

Handlebars 1.2.1

Ember 1.1.2

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subcontroller_template">
    foo
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="controller_template">
    {{! This piece of code throws an error}}
    {{!--
    {{#each subcontrollers}}
        {{view this.view}}
    {{/each}}
    --}}

    <p>subcontrollerContainers:</p>
    {{#each subcontrollerContainers}}
        {{view this.key.view}}
    {{/each}}

    <p>subcontrollerCollection:</p>
    {{#collection subcontrollerCollection}}
        {{view view.content.view}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var TemplatedViewController = Ember.Object.extend({
    templateFunction: null,
    viewArgs: null,
    viewBaseClass: Ember.View,
    view: function () {
        var controller = this;
        var viewArgs = this.get('viewArgs') || {};
        var args = {
            template: controller.get('templateFunction'),
            controller: controller
        };
        args = $.extend(viewArgs, args);
        return this.get('viewBaseClass').extend(args);
    }.property('templateFunction', 'viewArgs'),
    appendView: function (selector) {
        this.get('view').create().appendTo(selector);
    },
    appendViewToBody: function () {
        this.get('view').create().append();
    },
    appendPropertyViewToBody: function (property) {
        this.get(property).create().append();
    }
});

var Subcontroller = TemplatedViewController.extend({
    view: function () {
        var controller = this;
        return this.get('viewBaseClass').extend({
            controller: controller,
            templateName: 'subcontroller_template'
        });
    }.property()
});

var Controller = TemplatedViewController.extend({
    view: function () {
        var controller = this;
        return this.get('viewBaseClass').extend({
            controller: controller,
            templateName: 'controller_template'
        });
    }.property(),
    subcontrollers: null,
    init: function () {
        var subcontrollers = [];
        subcontrollers.pushObject(Subcontroller.create());
        subcontrollers.pushObject(Subcontroller.create());
        subcontrollers.pushObject(Subcontroller.create());
        this.set('subcontrollers', subcontrollers);
    },
    subcontrollerContainers: function () {
        var that = this;
        return this.get('subcontrollers').map(function (item, index, enumerable) {
            return that.createSubcontrollerContainer(item);
        });
    }.property('subcontrollers.@each'),
    createSubcontrollerContainer: function (subcontroller) {
        return Ember.Object.create({key: subcontroller});
    },
    subcontrollerCollection: function () {
        return Ember.CollectionView.extend({
            content: this.get('subcontrollers')
        });
    }.property('subcontrollers')
});

var controller = Controller.create();

$(function () {
    controller.appendView('#main');
});
```

Comment: Ember uses certain keywords.  `Controller` is one of them.  For posterity, you should change your naming convention and then try it again.  Also, why are you constructing custom controllers off of Ember.Object?

Comment: @gravityplanx The only place in the code where I see `controller` used as a reserved name is as a property of view objects.  In those cases I am using it correctly.  Removing the `controller` property from the views will cause them not to render.  As far as I can tell the problem I described is not related to the use of reserved names.  Please point out which variable named `controller` is the problem.

Comment: @gravityplanx The reason I am making custom controllers is just because I learned Ember.js early on before many of the classes that exist now were invented.  Which class do you suggest I use in place of `TemplatedViewController`?

Comment: The code is strange. It's more like a Backbone code but not Ember code. In Ember it has Ember.Controller, and with route it's no need to create controllers manually. Can you explain why you want to do in this way?

Comment: @darkbaby123 The only reason is familiarity.  I learned Ember before there was a router.  The goal of the code is to connect the controller with the view.  I'm doing it through a closure on a property and it seems the normal way to do it in Ember is through the template language with a controllerBinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. It seems like having a property named "view" conflicts with an ember naming convention. Checkout this working link. I just changed the computed property "view" to "conView"
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zowat/1/edit

Comment: Yes good point.  It seems the name "view" is reserved when used this way.  It also seems that my code is written inside out.  It would be better to write inside the each loop `{{view App.MyView controllerBinding="this"}}` rather than putting the view as a property of `Subcontroller`.